# Arbitrary Code Injection - serialize-javascript@1.9.1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, code-injection, penetration-testing

There is a high severity issue in the package **serialize-javascript@1.9.1**. I'm not able to visualize why this is a high issue here and how attackers can take advantage of this to do some damages to websites. Could someone please give some more examples? Or maybe explain in more details to help me understand. Thank you.

Link:
https://snyk.io/test/npm/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/2.2.0?tab=issues

I tried to write the following code and I still don't see why this is a big security issue.

```
const serialize = require('serialize-javascript');

let result = serialize({"foo": /1" + console.log(1)/i, "bar": '"@__R-<UID>-0__@'})
console.log(result);
result = eval('(' + serialize({"foo": /1" + console.log(1)/i, "bar": '"@__R-<UID>-0__@'}) + ')');
console.log(result);
```

Console logs

```
{"foo":/1" + console.log(1)/i,"bar":"\"@__R-\u003CUID\u003E-0__@"}
{ foo: /1" + console.log(1)/i, bar: '"@__R-<UID>-0__@' }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to confirm based only on what you have posted, however, this is running `eval()` against presumably untrusted data which may run malicious code. I am doubtful that Snyk can fully confirm the exploitability of this.